# Problems generating a form in javascript [HTML5]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to generate a form for use with my game, I have to say, JavaScript is a whole new world from what I'm used to, and not being able to just create text-fields inside of the canvas is pretty lame, (Or atleast I haven't found a way to... that works with mobile devices)

Here's my code:

```
var loginForm;
var formUserInput;
var formSubmit;

loginForm = document.createElement("form");
loginForm.setAttribute('method', "post");
loginForm.setAttribute('action', 'doSomething()');

formUserInput = document.createElement("input");
formUserInput.setAttribute('type', "text");
formUserInput.setAttribute('name', "username");

formSubmit = document.createElement("input");
formSubmit.setAttribute('type', "submit");
formSubmit.value = "Submit";

loginForm.appendChild(formUserInput);
loginForm.appendChild(formSubmit);

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(loginForm);
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Online RPG Alpha </title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/engine/networking.js"></script>
    <script src="js/engine/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/entity/Player.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CanvasManager.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When debugging the page I don't get any javascript errors, but the form never appears, and it also is not appended to the source. I also tried using `$("body").append(loginForm);` which is jQuery, but it also didn't work.

This is the generated HTML:

```
<html><head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Online RPG Alpha </title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/engine/networking.js"></script>
    <script src="js/engine/phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/entity/Player.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CanvasManager.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game" style="overflow: hidden;"><canvas width="800" height="600" style="display: block; touch-action: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); cursor: inherit;"></canvas></div>

</body></html>
```

The JavaScript is located inside of the "js/CanvasManager.js" script.

Comment: Is your code inside an onload or ready block?

Comment: Assuming you place your code in a script block just before `</body>` (to ensure that the `body` element is available in the DOM) your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/nvLnhjrz/

Comment: Can you be more specific of which browser you're using and what exact behavior you're expecting, I see the login form (input field and the submit button) just fine as this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3wyxtL00/) shows.

Comment: *Where* do you have the JavaScript code, and how is it associated with the HTML document?

Comment: Try to create a HTML form, with `display: none` and when you want to show the form, just use `$('form').show();`.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - JS code is inside the CanvasManager.js script.

Comment: @Jonast92 - Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your JavaScript code is in an external file that is referred to via a `script` element in the `head` part, the code gets executed when the browser is still processing the `head` part and hasn’t even started reading the `body` element. Thus, there is no `body` element in the DOM, so the append fails. In the browser console log, you should see an error message like the following:

> TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...)[0] is undefined

There are several ways to fix this. One way is to move the element

```
<script src="js/CanvasManager.js"></script>
```

at the end of the body, right before the end tag `</body>`.

A cleaner way is to wrap the code in a function and assign it to be executed once the page has loaded:

```
window.onload = function() {
  // your current code goes here
};
```

This way the logic won’t depend on the placement of the `script` element.